# Cannot type into text input on jqModal dialog when modal set to true

Tags: jqmodal

Having upgraded jqModal from r13 to r22, I find that where my dialogs contain text inputs it is not possible to type into them. Removing `modal:true` from the settings fixes it, but I don't want my users to be able to dismiss the dialog by clicking on the overlay. Is this behaviour by design, or is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly not by design. I have released a fix (+r23). Please open a github issue if you require further assistance.

Related:

- If you're nesting modals, be sure to have a higher z-index value on child modals.
- You may override the $.jqm.focusFunc() to provide custom behaviour for events occurring outside the currently active modal.

Comment: Thanks very much, that does seem to fix the problem.